# User's access to resources via daemon using OpenID

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid

OpenID, built on-top of OAuth 2.0, provides various mechanisms for authenticating an user/application alongside authorization to specified resources.

Generally, OAuth 2.0 aids in giving third parties the ability to request access to a user's data within your system but does also provide a standard username/password authentication method.

**For a daemon or "offline" style application written by a user, what would be the appropriate authentication flow?**

The application will also be using roles to determine the user's level of access to a group's resources.

Answer (score 2):

If the application is written by a user and the user trusts the environment in which that application runs, one could use the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to achieve what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to generate access tokens with OpenID? For example, in Github I can create tokens that allow apps access to a specific repository.

Comment: yes, by default/design OpenID Connect provides an access token as well as an id_token